# relative url with url rewrite rule in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

After creating url rewrite rule in .htaccess file, then relative url are not work.
suppose, my url is

```
example.com/review/alias/455
```

then, my relative url ( href="example.php" ) is creates a problem like,

```
example.com/review/alias/example.php
```

rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^review/([a-z\-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ review.php?alias=$1&id=$2 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your current rules.

Comment: rewrite rule is added in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^review/([a-z\-]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ review.php?alias=$1&id=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: it not work for css, js files

Comment: use <base href="ww.yoursite.com"> in head tag of your page

Comment: this condition not work.

Comment: <base href="ww.yoursite.com"> is work thankyou